# using target attribute with form to open the link in same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web app. I used form as a drop down menu so that it displays the information about the category users selected. But when I select an option the link is opening in new window. I want it to open in the same window. I used target attribute with form like this

```
<form id="aform" target="_self">
<select id="mymenu">
<option selected>Choose a category</option>
<option value="moblist.html" target="self">Mobiles</option>
<option value="" >Tablets</option>
<option value="">Laptops</option>
<option value="">Bikes</option>
<option value="">Car</option>
</select>
</form>
```

my java scrip is

```
var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
selectmenu.onchange=function(){ //run some code when "onchange" event fires
var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex] //this refers to "selectmenu"
if (chosenoption.value!="nothing"){
window.open(chosenoption.value, "", "") //open target site (based on option's value                attr) in new window
}
}
```

but still the link is opening in new window. How can I make the selected page to open in the same window.

Comment: With the `window.open(chosenoption.value, "", "")`, you get a new window. You'll need to set the page's `src` value to `chosenoption.value`.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I changed the code like window.open(chosenoption.value, "_self", "") and it is working now

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS Why not extract your comment into the answers section so he can accept it. That way, future users can see the resolution if they come across this.

Comment: ya sure @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS I will surely do so

Answer (score 1):

With the

```
window.open(chosenoption.value, "", "")
```

you get a new window. You'll need to set the page's `src` value to `chosenoption.value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the target attribute altogether.

```
<form id="aform">
...
```

should be enough to open it in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Window.open opens a new browser window. I found this on this site:

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)